# VirtualBox: Bridged Connection Not Working - High Sierra

Tags: network, high-sierra, virtualization, virtualbox

I just bought my first Macbook today (long time Windows user) but I am running into issues loading in the .OVA of Rapid 7's "[Hackazon](https://github.com/rapid7/hackazon)" vulnerable web app into VirtualBox and getting a bridged connection so that I can scan it and connect to it. I know there are lots of these questions that have been posted about networking with VMs in other forms, but I have followed all of the suggestions from a dozen pages and nothing seems to work, and I would really like to not regret buying this machine.

Here is my setup:

**VirtualBox Settings Screenshot:**
[image: VirtualBox Settings Screenshot]

**Screenshot of error on VM load**
[image: Screenshot of the error that I get when the VM loads]

**Screenshot of ifconfig on the VM**
[image: Screenshot if ifconfig output of the VM]

Since this is a brand new machine, are there any Mac permissions networking configurations that I should be aware of? Am I missing something dumb? This generally worked when I used VMs in the past on Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing your adapter type from Intel to PC-net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh--strange! So it turns out that it was something with that particular .ova file. I just downloaded Ubuntu and it was able to bridge no problem. I guess that's something that I need to report to Rapid7.